# Selecting 36V, 12V and 9V from 3 different PSUs

Tags: mosfet, switches, switch-mode-power-supply

currently i am designing a system in a machine. One of the feature is it can select power supply between 36V (overvoltage), 12V and 9V (under-voltage). Max current would be 300mA @ 12, while 9V which considered as under-volt operates only 90mA.

Previously i have designed by using Relay module. And these relays are controlled by MCU.[image: relay switch]

However, now i am considering to use MOSFTET. which in my understanding, MOSFET have a longer lifespan than Relays.

Therefor, i am seeking help from you guys to help me in choose which MOSFET is considered OK with the operating power given as above, and also, how should i design the MOSFET Circuit?

your help and support is much appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: the tricky thing with MOSFETs is that they don't isolate, so you'll probably need a 36V signal to control the 36V mosfet and that they have an internal diode, so keeping the 36V out of the 12V could be tricky.

Comment: I do not understand the overvoltage and undervoltage options. Can the user select those? Why are they available, and how are they related to the question?

Comment: Hi, sorry that i didn't mentioned in detail. Yes user can select those. They are for fault handling purpose. Where, whenever product is supplied with over/under, it should give out fault signal to the MCU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly as @Jasen says, naive application of drain-coupled P-MOSFETS will give you a nasty surprise. When 9V is active, the FETs for 12V and 36V will still see their diode reverse-biased so all is well. When 12V or 36V are active, all voltages below will see their diode *forward* biased and two or more FETs will fight over control of the voltage. Whichever one loses will probably release its magic smoke.

Consider instead PNP BJTs. The critical parameters to look for are

- Max Ic > 300mA
- Max Vce breakdown > 36V
- Low Vce sat

You have not specified how much voltage drop between the supply and the load you can tolerate, but 500mV Vcesat is frequent, 200mV possible (depending on how much you want to spend). Consider the [PBSS5540Z](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PBSS5540Z.pdf) with

- Ic > -5A
- Vce >= -40V
- Rcesat ~ 55mohm, for a loss of ~17mV at 300mA

You have not shown what drives your MNB and MF1-2 signals. You'll probably need low-side, open-drain-style switching to appropriately bias your PNPs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0XqSu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>